# Log File to NSString

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am using this to get the log files data:

```
NSFileHandle *file;
file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:@"~/Library/Application Support/RepoManager/*.log"];
NSData *filedata;
filedata = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
NSString *logC;
logC = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:filedata encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

And than write them using this:

```
NSString *formatString = @"Log: %@";
return [NSString stringWithFormat:formatString, *logC.stringValue];
```

But it says logC does not contain a string value

Answer (score 1):

NSString does not define a `.stringValue` property, and even if it did, `*logC.stringValue` would have no useful meaning in Objective-C. `logC` itself is what you want to be using as your format parameter. (It's the string containing the contents of the log file.)

Comment: So what do i need to change it to?

Comment: Just use `logC` instead of `*logC.stringValue`.

Comment: Poroperty 'strinngValue' not found on object of type 'NSString *'

Comment: any ideas on what to do now?